# Solr in Production environment ( in Tomcat )

Tags: apache, tomcat, search, solr, tomcat7

Can someone tell me about the areas I should be concerned about when releasing Solr for my production environment.

Currently **Tomcat** is set up in a **Redhat** machine, need to plug **Solr** so that ***Solr could work in Tomcat ( instead of Jetty )***. Is this possible?

I've read many articles and tried out many things, but still couldn't get it to work.

Anyone out there who has tried this stunt and lived? would like to hear what you have to say and how you performed your stunt so that I could make mine work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, just follow the Tomcat chapter in [the official release documentation](http://mirror.switch.ch/mirror/apache/dist/lucene/solr/ref-guide/apache-solr-ref-guide-4.7.pdf) and for further details [the guide in the wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat). If you already did this maybe you can post details what didn't work?